# How exactly works the setTimeout() JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following doubt related the **setTimeout()** method.

So into a test script I have:

```
function simpleMessage() {
    alert("This is just an alert box");
}

// settimeout is in milliseconds:
setTimeout(simpleMessage, 5000);
```

So when I perform the page, after 5 second the **simpleMessage()** function is performed and it is shown the alert popup.

I understand that when I do:

```
setTimeout(simpleMessage, 5000);
```

it means that the **simpleMessage()** function have to be performed after 5 second after the timer settings but why it is used **simpleMessage** and not **simpleMessage()** for the function invocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to `setTimeout` is the function to be executed. The identifier `simpleMessage` refers to the function you want `setTimeout` to execute, so that's what you supply as an argument to `setTimeout`.

If you did `setTimeout(simpleMessage(), 5000);`, you would execute `simpleMessage` immediately and then `setTimeout` would get the *return value* as its first argument. This is comparable to:

```
var value = simpleMessage();
setTimeout(value, 5000);
```

This doesn't make sense; it is the same as `setTimeout(simpleMessage(), 5000);`.

Consider also a higher-order function that returns a function:

```
function funcFacotry() {
    return function() { alert("this is just an alert box."); }
}

var simpleMessage = funcFactory();
setTimeout(simpleMessage, 5000);
```

In this case, this actually *does* make sense, because the return value of `funcFactory` *is* actually a function itself.

Answer (score 5):

`simpleMessage` is a **reference** to a function whereas `simpleMessage()` executes the function. `setTimeout` needs a function **reference** to call a later time.

To perhaps make things a little more obvious, you could have written your function declaration as

```js
// define my function (but don't execute it)
var myFunction = function() {
    alert('SOUND THE ALARMS!');
};

// start a timer that will execute the given function after the given
// period of time
setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
```

See [`setTimeout` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to pass a reference to [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) of the function you want to invoke after the 5s.

This:

```
setTimeout(simpleMessage(), 5000);
```

would execute the simpleMessage function at the same time you're calling the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` in javascript executes the function after a specific amount of time set as the second parameter, while if you use with `setInterval` it will execute in intervals, without to consider if the function is get executed or not (this will lead to chunkiness for example if you ar using for animation).

As a metter of second question: if you are using the function with parentheses, this is a method invocation, while using without parentheses is a reference to a specific method.